# Can't make condition over my terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to find all AWS vpcs and add vpc flow logs to them.
I'm deploying this code to all my AWS accounts, around 30 accounts.
4 of them doesn't have any VPC, so it fails on them.

this vpc module is launched from the account module (just a module that specify modules to launch), unfortunatly, count on module directly doesn't work yet in 0.12

I tried to pass a bool variable vpc_exists = false to the accounts where there is no VPC, and make some condition so it doesn't run on the accounts without VPC, but i couldn't make it.

Works if I have at least one VPC, but fails if no VPC :

```
data "aws_vpcs" "vpcs" {}

resource "aws_flow_log" "vpc_flow_log" {
  count           = length(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)
  vpc_id          = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]
  iam_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_logs.arn
  log_destination = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.vpc_flow_logs[count.index].arn
  traffic_type    = "REJECT"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)
  name  = "${var.prefix}-vpc-flow-logs-${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]}"
}
```

`count = var.vpc_exists ? length(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids) : 0`

Adding the condition to the resources ask me :

```
  on ../modules/vpc/vpc_flow_logs.tf line 32, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs":
  32:   name  = "${var.prefix}-vpc-flow-logs-${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]}"

Because data.aws_vpcs.vpcs has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on
specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    data.aws_vpcs.vpcs[count.index]
```

if I do add the [count.index] inside the count, it won't work.

Don't know what to do anymore, any ideas ?

Edit :

following some advices, i added .*., but i still get into error :

```
data "aws_vpcs" "vpcs" {
  count = var.vpc_exists ? 1 : 0
}

resource "aws_flow_log" "vpc_flow_log" {
  count = var.vpc_exists ? length(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.*.ids) : 0
  vpc_id          = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]
  iam_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_logs.arn
  log_destination = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.vpc_flow_logs[count.index].arn
  traffic_type    = "REJECT"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs" {
  count = var.vpc_exists ? length(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.*.ids) : 0
  name  = "${var.prefix}-vpc-flow-logs-${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]}"
}
```

```
  on ../modules/vpc/vpc_flow_logs.tf line 32, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs":
  32:   name  = "${var.prefix}-vpc-flow-logs-${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.ids)[count.index]}"

Because data.aws_vpcs.vpcs has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on
specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    data.aws_vpcs.vpcs[count.index]
```

If I add the .*. to the name line, and vpc_id line, i will get this error :

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value

  on ../modules/vpc/vpc_flow_logs.tf line 32, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs":
  32:   name  = "${var.prefix}-vpc-flow-logs-${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.*.ids)[count.index]}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | data.aws_vpcs.vpcs is tuple with 1 element

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: Pretty sure that should be `data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.*.ids`

Comment: following your recommendation, it works to add it on count, but on vpc_id line : ```Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../modules/vpc/vpc_flow_logs.tf line 24, in resource "aws_flow_log" "vpc_flow_log":
  24:   vpc_id          = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs.*.ids)[count.index]

Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_id": string required.```

Comment: if I add then the : .*. to the count line and ```vpc_id          = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.vpcs[count.index].ids)[count.index]```, terraform works but wants to delete every flow_log except the number 0.